# Show cell value where row and column intersects

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get cell value which is at the intersection of row and column number entered by user, as like in matrices, like if user enters row 5 and column 4 then my result should show the value present in the cell [5.4].

I am getting row and column number as:

```
 <td>Please enter the temperature:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="temp" /></td>

 <td>Please enter the column:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="col" /></td>
 <td><input type="submit" name="go" /></td>
```

i am redirecting these values to **find.php** page, where i am doing this:

```
$entry1 = $_POST['temp'];
$entry2 = $_POST['col'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tables WHERE Temperature LIKE '".$entry1."'
AND   COLUMN_NAME = '".$entry2."' ");
```

and showing my result as

```
<td ><?php echo (don't know what to write here) ;  ?></td>
```

i know i am making lot of mistakes but do not know how to fix them. Please show me way.

Comment: You need to fetch the value with `mysql_fetch_array`.... o,o

Comment: why you are using `LIKE` for comparing value in temperature ? is it typo or done in with a reason

Comment: @Cheezburger i am using `mysql_fetch_array` for getting my results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get values at `[Temperature ,COLUMN_NAME]` then change query to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tables WHERE Temperature = '".$entry1."'
AND   COLUMN_NAME = '".$entry2."' ");
```

Because LIKE will look all string containing `$entry1`.

For example if `$entry = 10` the it will select column with values like `10, 110, 100,...`

after executing the query fetch data like this

if the no of rows returned is more than one the loop it with while like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row[$entry2];
}
```

or if it return only one value or you need only first value when it returns more than one value try this

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[$entry2];
```

Also try to avoid using `mysql_*` functions and start using `mysqli_*` function or `PDO`

Comment: `$entry2` is actually column name so how i should echo it as it is variable? if it was constant then i can use `echo $row['colname'];` bt in my case colname is inside `$entry2`.

Comment: use `echo $row[$entry2]`